# How to make Post request by list action for create function in viewsets in DRF

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I want to send post request from testing. Its working for postman but it didnot work for my test case. How can I give the data by post request.
Views.py,

```
class PersonalInfoAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerPermission]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Employee.objects.all(), pk=pk)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

    def create(self, request):
        personal_info = JSONParser().parse(request)
         .....
    return ...
```

test.py

```
 url = reverse('employee1-list')
        self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        resp1 = self.client.post(url, {"data": {
            "appraisal_master_id": 1,
            "personal_info": {
                "employee_id": 1,
                "experience": "abcd",
                "education": "Nonoooo"
            }
        }
        }, format='json')
        print(resp1)
        self.assertEqual(resp1.status_code, 200)
```

I have got 400 error. Please, tell anyone how can I pass data im properway,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. When I gave request which passes dictionary data. then, I coverted into json its working fine.

```
url = reverse('employee1-list')
        self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        resp1 = self.client.post(url, data=data, content_type="application/json")
        print(resp1)
        self.assertEqual(resp1.status_code, 201)
```

Comment: I just removed format='json' then added content type.. Hope it helps anyone,..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).